# How to append a nested list?

Tags: python, list, append

today I started studying Python and have a question. I want to append the list itself, for example

`a = [0, 1, 2]`

want to make `[0, 1, 2, [0, 1, 2]]` by using function `.append`

`a.append(a)` gets result like `[0, 1, 2, [...]]`

Is it the correct answer? I don't know why the answer has `[...]` thing.

Also, what is the difference when I do this?

```
b = a.append(a)
print(b)
>> None
```

Comment: Conceptually, how does appending something to itself play out for you? I mean, literally thinking like a computer

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please edit your question and include what *exact* output you want? Also please don't include multiple questions in a single post.

Comment: @roganjosh I don't understand your question exactly, but I was just studying about "list function" and trying some examples. And thought how would this thing have result?

Comment: @AbhyudayVaish Ok, I'll try to keep your advice next time. By the way, why I shouldn't include multiple questions in one post? I don't know the system. Sorry.

Comment: @JamesJang No worries! You can have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn more.

Comment: I mean actually thinking about it. What do you think happens when a list is appended to itself? How does that not set off a thought process of infinite loops for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `[1, 2, 3, [...]]` is the correct answer. It is the way python represents recursive lists.
   Basically what that means is `a = [1, 2, 3, [1, 2, 3, [1, 2, 3, [...]]]]` infinite times.
2. `list.append` returns `None`. `a.append(a)` therefore returns `None` and if you store that in `b` and print it, `None` is the correct answer

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I understood question 1. But a little confused about the second answer. What do you mean list.append returns None?

Comment: `a` is a `list` and `list` defines a method called `append`. This method appends the item in-place, nothing is returned. And when nothing is returned python implicitly returns `None`.